# Uploading a blob to appstore: query parameters to GET upload url

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-rest-framework, blobstore

I am working from the BLOB upload example in [App Engine for Python : Uploading a BLOB](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Uploading_a_blob)
The only difference is that since I was using Django REST framework already, I decided to use it instead of webapp2 to implement the **MainHandler** class in the example code (& I am not using a form)

```
class PdfUploadUrl(APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ##
        # Fetch the URL to which we upload the PDF
        ##
        log.debug('PdfUploadUrl: request.GET = %s:%s', type(request.GET), request.GET)
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/pdfservice/upload')
        log.debug('PdfUploadUrl: upload_url = %s : %s', type(upload_url), upload_url)
        return Response(dict(upload_url=str(upload_url)))
```

When I call it from cURL as such

```
curl -i -G http://<my_app>.appspot.com/pdf/uploadurl
```

the response is

```
{"upload_url": "http://<my-app>.appspot.com/_ah/upload/AMmfu6au0EGRyH1ywfoJbR1XrLBM7V0JOAdVXwluktrBopvSBqh4DB1XIq6bzyvR9gpIfjfKAPREaWqCvkIb-i6MUQDf3eKMSdUhbS6punL1gn5dqUZckJIEU3_e78KxgRXDaH71D423/ALBNUaYAAAAAUwbj7SpdDkib8f2H8JQ6hlYA8-cTheTy/"}
```

Now, when I change the request to

```
curl -i -G http://<my-app>.appspot.com/pdf/uploadurl?xyz=bc
```

then, the Response is

```
{"upload_url": "http://<my-app>.appspot.com/_ah/upload/?xyz=bc/AMmfu6b4YEpDMuiFI494dY39yCCAehiAykQ2hy8fWEo1GS7kuQ6BKG9zR8TJhfDzlWbH6Fvc9TZWNBGTca7PY3DxY8f8-KKiKzIbS2k09CeMXBGVhfJE_EgGH0l_P3pL1ndVmL-6lGOF/ALBNUaYAAAAAUwbjrZJHTdW6rGDJZxLCuwbq46bw3Bk7/"}
```

which is actually an unusable URL. How is it that the query params are messing up the call to

```
     blobstore.create_upload_url()
```

Comment: Can you include more code? The call blobstore.create_upload_url('/pdfservice/upload') doesn't include the query string. So I assume you're not showing us everything.

Comment: Actually, I take it back. The URL is usable although it is puzzling that the dev server behaves differently from the production server in that the prod server seems to incorporate query params in generating the upload URL.

Comment: It's unusable if the url contains %27 (single quote). For example, `curl -i -G http://<my-app>.appspot.com/pdf/uploadurl?xyz=%27` results in an unusable URL.